# C# : Switch between power plans

Tags: c#, windows, registry

i am creating an API and i want to switch between power plans

> [Balanced , High performance , Power
>   saver]

, my problem isn`t on the code , coding is easy , but i want to know where can i find these power planes .exe files or even values in registry to modify it

Comment: If you're creating an API, wouldn't you want to offer your customers the highest performance available at all times? Unless you have a huge number of machines, then the energy cost couldn't be that great...

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer He means he wants to change the current Windows power plan (e.g. you might want power-saver on a laptop, for example).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Separate from C#, in 2011 [Raymond Chen recommended](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110510-00/?p=10703) that users use the GUI, or for those who prefer a terminal:

If you are using Vista or above, from the command line, run :

```
powercfg -aliases
```

However, this doesn't work for me as `-aliases` is not a valid switch on Windows XP.

**EDIT**: Or, you can just use this [list of helpful GUIDs](http://blogs.technet.com/b/richardsmith/archive/2007/11/29/powercfg-useful-if-you-know-the-guids.aspx)!

Comment: `powercfg -L` should be a valid alternative.  It could be used in conjunction with `powercfg -GETACTIVESCHEME` and `powercfg -SETACTIVESCHEME` to do the switching

Comment: @ZombieSheep That doesn't show the numerical IDs - it only shows the "friendly" name. I tried `-L -N` as well, but no joy.

Comment: Interesting - on my machine it shows the full GUID and name of the schemes.  Having said that, the ALIASES switch is also present, so maye it is an OS version dependent thing.  (Win 7 Enterprise here)

Comment: @ZombieSheep Yeah - I checked and it looks like the aliases switch was introduced in Vista.

Answer (score 4):

While you could certainly use an external tool like powercfg, you could just as well use the Power Management API

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372711%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Or Windows Management Instrumenation (WMI)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd904518%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You'll find them in the winnt.h SDK header file.  Stored in c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v6.0a\include for VS2008, v7.0a for VS2010.  Search for "GUID_MAX_POWER_SAVINGS" to find this:

```
// =========================================
// Define GUIDs which represent well-known power schemes
// =========================================
//

//
// Maximum Power Savings - indicates that very aggressive power savings measures will be used to help
//                         stretch battery life.
//
// {a1841308-3541-4fab-bc81-f71556f20b4a}
//
DEFINE_GUID( GUID_MAX_POWER_SAVINGS, 0xA1841308, 0x3541, 0x4FAB, 0xBC, 0x81, 0xF7, 0x15, 0x56, 0xF2, 0x0B, 0x4A );

//
// No Power Savings - indicates that almost no power savings measures will be used.
//
// {8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c}
//
DEFINE_GUID( GUID_MIN_POWER_SAVINGS, 0x8C5E7FDA, 0xE8BF, 0x4A96, 0x9A, 0x85, 0xA6, 0xE2, 0x3A, 0x8C, 0x63, 0x5C );

//
// Typical Power Savings - indicates that fairly aggressive power savings measures will be used.
//
// {381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e}
//
DEFINE_GUID( GUID_TYPICAL_POWER_SAVINGS, 0x381B4222, 0xF694, 0x41F0, 0x96, 0x85, 0xFF, 0x5B, 0xB2, 0x60, 0xDF, 0x2E );
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of Power Management API usage: [PowerManager.cs](https://github.com/andy722/power-plan-switcher/blob/master/PlanSwitcher/PowerManager.cs)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Powercfg](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748940%28WS.10%29.aspx) command from command-line